# Rendering labels taking long time

Tags: cytoscape.js

I have >1000 nodes. Label rendering for these nodes takes about 35 seconds. How can I reduce this time? When I look at the chrome developers tool, I see that cytoscape's label projection calculation taking this time. Could you please help on how to reduce this time or if it is fixed in latest versions? Label displaying is must , cannot just show in tooltip.

Comment: can you please post your code, we can't exactly tell you what you can do better without seeing your code first, thanks!

Comment: I am just using standard config to display label. Here is the style json excerpt.  "selector": "node",
 "style": {
  "label": "data(label)",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much you can do about the performance. It is generally bad when the size of the graph is over a thousand nodes/edges.

You can use some kind of semantic zooming (i.e. reveal more details about the graph based on zoom level), to increase the performance. In your case, this is showing or hiding labels based on the zoom level. There is an option for that `min-zoomed-font-size`.

Also check [this](http://js.cytoscape.org/#performance) out for more performance tuning.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement your idea